# Jdialog passes back user credentials to its containing JFrame? Or, JFrame gets credentials from its JDialog?

Tags: java, swing, authentication, passwords, polymorphism

how do I pass the user credentials **back** to the containing JFrame, so that the specific user is known by the JFrame?  The JFrame has a main method.

Can the containing JFrame somehow get the user from the `Dialog`?

when the `jbtOk` `actionListener` finds an acceptable `User`, then...?

```
package legacy.gui.general;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import legacy.database.User;
import legacy.database.Users;

public class LoginDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LoginDialog.class.getName());
    private final JLabel jlblUsername = new JLabel("Username");
    private final JLabel jlblPassword = new JLabel("Password");
    private final JTextField jtfUsername = new JTextField(15);
    private final JPasswordField jpfPassword = new JPasswordField();
    private final JButton jbtOk = new JButton("Login");
    private final JButton jbtCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    private final JLabel jlblStatus = new JLabel(" ");

    public LoginDialog() {
        this(null, true);
    }

    public LoginDialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        log.info("simple constructor..");
        initComponents();
    }

    public LoginDialog(final JFrame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        log.info("complex constructor..");
        JPanel p3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        p3.add(jlblUsername);
        p3.add(jlblPassword);
        JPanel p4 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        p4.add(jtfUsername);
        p4.add(jpfPassword);
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.add(p3);
        p1.add(p4);
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.add(jbtOk);
        p2.add(jbtCancel);
        JPanel p5 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p5.add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        p5.add(jlblStatus, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        jlblStatus.setForeground(Color.RED);
        jlblStatus.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(p5, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        jbtOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                List<User> users = new Users().getUsers();
                for (User u : users) {
                    if (Arrays.equals(u.getPassword().toCharArray(), jpfPassword.getPassword())
                            && u.getUser().equals(jtfUsername.getText())) {
                        parent.setVisible(true);
                        setVisible(false);
                    } else {
                        jlblStatus.setText("Invalid username or password");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        jbtCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setVisible(false);
                parent.dispose();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 580, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 389, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

the JFrame creates the Dialog:

```
public MainFrame() {
    initComponents();
    passDialog = new LoginDialog(this, true);
    passDialog.setVisible(true);
    //     setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, create a private instance field called `User`...

```
private User user;
```

Next, change you `Login` `ActionListener` to store the matching user...

```
jbtOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        List<User> users = new Users().getUsers();
        for (User u : users) {
            if (Arrays.equals(u.getPassword().toCharArray(), jpfPassword.getPassword())
                    && u.getUser().equals(jtfUsername.getText())) {
                user = u;
                dispose();
                break;
            } else {
                jlblStatus.setText("Invalid username or password");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Next, create a method in your `LoginDialog` to allow the caller to get the `User` value...

```
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}
```

Next, when the `LoginDialog` is closed, get the `User`...

```
public MainFrame() {
    initComponents();
    passDialog = new LoginDialog(this, true);
    passDialog.setVisible(true);
    User user = passDialog.getUser();
}
```

**Side notes**

- Don't try and control the caller from the `LoginDialog`.  It is not the login dialogs responsibility to determine what should happen if the user selects to `Cancel`, for example.  The `LoginDialog` should simply do it's contractual job (collect the user details and verify the credentials) and leave the rest up to the caller...

Comment: Well, basically, you are changing the visibility state of the parent window (as well as disposing of it if the user selects cancel), that's really beyond the scope of the responsibility of the dialog (one might argue that actually validating the credentials is beyond the scope of it's responsibility, but that's an argument for another day).  You dialog (and even components) should never modify, directly, the state of other components, this should be done through the use of some kind of arguable contract (like a model or listener).  Think, no side effects.

Comment: There should be no side effects of you calling the `LoginDialog`, it should collect the details from the user and validate them, that's all, nothing else.  Think of it this way.  If you hadn't written the the dialog and were using a 3rd party library, would you really want it messing with your window ... in any way ...

Comment: yes, in this case it's a bit of faux security, but serves the purpose for the time being.  I'll look into it, certainly.  I agree with your statements, just thinking about the implications.